# For regular tetrahedron $ABCD$ with center $O$, and $\overrightarrow{NO}=-3\overrightarrow{MO}$, is $NA+NB+NC+ND\geq MA+MB+MC+MD$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABCD$  be a regular tetrahedron with center $O.$ Consider two points $M,N,$ such that $\overrightarrow{NO}=-3\overrightarrow{MO}.$ Prove or disprove that 
>   $$NA+NB+NC+ND\geq MA+MB+MC+MD$$

I tried to use CS in the Euclidean space $E_3$, but it does not help, because the minoration is too wide.
Note: I also posted this [on the Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485563/for-regular-tetrahedron-abcd-with-center-o-and-overrightarrowno-3-over), but not much progress has been made on this question. This is why I thought that posting here too would be all right (this problem is open in the sense that its proposer doesn't have a proof, so I guess it is fit the for this forum).
EDIT: The bounty expired, so this may be reopened.

Comment: what are these $NA$, $NB$, etc.? Distances?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Yes, they are distances.

Comment: I think it’s inappropriate to post this here while there’s a bounty on the question at the other site, with upvotes and comments and an answer.

Comment: @MattF. I pondered over this aspect before posting, as I know that crossposting is not encouraged, but I reached the conclusion that it would be all right since it has been there for a while and little progress has been made(the only answer there was for the 2D case and I encouraged that user to post it since I had got no response to the problem and I thought that maybe it would somehow prove to be useful for the 3D case in which I am interested). I hoped that by posting here I would draw more attention to the problem. I am sorry if I were wrong, but I find this problem really interesting.

Comment: I wouldn’t object to posting here after the MSE bounty ends

Comment: The standard parametrization is the following: $$A(3,0,0); B(-1,2\sqrt2,0); C(-1,-\sqrt2,\sqrt6); D(-1,-\sqrt2,-\sqrt6).$$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is still a bounty on the question at Mathematics.

Comment: This may be reopened after the bounty expires.

Comment: Do you accept my answer?

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen Your answer is very good and I truly thank you for your help! I will probably accept it, I just thought that maybe I should wait a little longer in case some other solutions appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following suggestions on Stack Exchange, we use the  homothety with respect to $O$
 and factor $-3$.
If $X$ is a point, then $X'$ denotes the point for which  $\overrightarrow{XO}= -3 \overrightarrow{X'O}$.
So $M=N'$ and $A'$ is the midpoint of the face opposite to $A$.
One has $XY=3X'Y'$ and the desired inequality becomes
$3MA'+3MB'+3MC'+3MD'\geq MA+MB+MC+MD$.

It thus suffices to prove inequalities of the type $MB'+MC'+MD'\geq MA$.
Thus put $f(X)=XB'+XC'+XD'-XA$. We have to show that $f(M)\geq0$.

Let us fix our tetrahedron as follows.

$A=\left(0,0,\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{6}}\right)$,

$B=   \left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{6}}\right)$,

$C=\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{6}}\right)$,

$D=\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{6}}\right)$.

Put $f_1(X)=XB'+XC'$, $f_2(X)=XD'-XA$, so that $f(X)=f_1(X)+f_2(X)$.

Notice that 
$f(O)=0$ and notice that $f(M)$ is positive if $M$ is far away from $O$.

Now take $M$ so that $f(M)$ is an absolute minimum.
Note that $f$ is positive at $A$, $B'$, $C'$, $D'$, so that $M$ is none of those points.
We have $f_2(M)<0$ and the gradients of $f_1$, $f_2$ cancel each other at $M$.
That means that the level sets through $M$ of $f_1$ and $f_2$ touch at $M$. (There is no point where both gradients vanish.)

The level set through $M$ of $f_1$ is an ellipsoid, with $f_1$ smaller inside, and the level set through $M$ of $f_2$ is the lower sheet 
of a hyperboloid of two sheets, with $f_2$ more negative inside the sheet.
As each level set is the curved boundary of a convex region, there is no other
point where the two level sets touch.

The level sets are symmetric with respect to the plane $ \left\{X\mid XB'=XC'
   \right\}$, so $M$ must lie on that plane. We have shown that $MB'=MC'$.
   Similarly $MC'=MD'$ and $M$ must be of the form $(0,0,x)$, so that
   $f(M)=\frac{\sqrt{72 x^2-4 \sqrt{6} x+3}-\sqrt{8 x^2-4
   \sqrt{6} x+3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\geq0$.

Comment: Why is $f_2(M)<0$ in your proof ? I see that $f_2$ can take negative values, but couldn't it be the case that the minimum of $f$ is reached at some point $M$ with $f_1(M)$ very small and $f_2(M)$ non-negative ?

Comment: @M.Dus. As it is a sum of two lengths, $f_1$ is positive.

Comment: Of course, but what I had not seen is that $f(O)=0$ so that you know the minimum is non-positive. Thank you anyway

Comment: I have clarified the text.